# How do I send an error response in Restlet?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, restlet

I have a Restlet `ServerResource`, which should process a GET request with a parameter `user`. If `user` is equal to some value, it should return some image, otherwise send an error response (404 or 403) indicating that the sender is not allowed to get the image.

```
import org.restlet.data.MediaType;
import org.restlet.representation.ObjectRepresentation;
import org.restlet.representation.Representation;
import org.restlet.resource.Get;
import org.restlet.resource.ResourceException;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;

public class GetMap extends ServerResource {
    @Get
    public Representation getImage() {
        final String user = getQuery().getValues("user");

        if (user.equals("me")) {
            //Read map from file and return it
            byte[] data = readImage();
            final ObjectRepresentation<byte[]> or=new ObjectRepresentation<byte[]>(data, MediaType.IMAGE_PNG) {
                @Override
                public void write(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
                    super.write(os);
                    os.write(this.getObject());
                }
            };
            return or;
        }
        return null; // Here I want to send an error response
    }
    [...]
}
```

How can I send a standardized error response in the `getImage` method (instead of `return null`) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the `ServerResource#setStatus(Status)` [method JavaDoc](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/2.3/gae/api/org/restlet/resource/ServerResource.html#setStatus%28org.restlet.data.Status%29%20) and the additional overloaded methods. Which allows you to return a Custom body along with the desired HTTP Status.

Alternatively throw a `new ResourceException` ([class JavaDoc](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/2.3/jee/api/org/restlet/resource/ResourceException.html?is-external=true)) the framework will convert these to the correct HTTP status and provide a default message, although this is unlikely to be an image.

This should meet your needs.  JavaDoc links to version 2.3.x on 25/11/2015

Answer (score 4):

In the past, I wrote a blog post about this:

- Exception handling with Restlet: https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/02/27/exception-handling-with-restlet/

In addition to the great Caleryn's answer, there is also now the `@Status` annotation to use custom exception within Restlet. A sample:

```
@Status(value = 400, serialize = true)
public class MyValidationException extends RuntimeException {
    public ServiceValidationException(String message, Exception e) {
        super(message, e);
    }
}
```

When such exception is thrown, Restlet automatically detects it and create  the corresponding error message. In the sample, a response with the status code `400` and it tries to serialize the exception as a bean to JSON (or something else) using the converter service.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry